# Dynamic PS-Worker Scheme Cannot Share Parameters in Cluster Propagation Mode

Tags: tensorflow, distributed-training

I'm trying to build a scalable distributed training system with a ps-worker scheme. In this scheme, every PS has information about all the PSs, and the number of PS stays constant. As for every worker, it only knows itself and all PS.

Using the Tensorflow cluster propagation method, I can start both the PSs and workers to keep the distributed training loop alive. But I found that each worker kept its own training process, and is not sharing data structures with others.

Here is a demo:

**demo.py**

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import time
import rest
import os
import sys
import traceback
from tensorflow.core.protobuf import config_pb2
from tensorflow.python.training import server_lib
from tensorflow.core.protobuf import cluster_pb2
from tensorflow.python.training import server_lib
from tensorflow.compat.v1.train import replica_device_setter
from tensorflow.python.client import timeline
from tensorflow.python.ops import data_flow_ops

tf.disable_v2_behavior()
flags = tf.app.flags
FLAGS = flags.FLAGS
flags.DEFINE_string('ps_list', '127.0.0.1:2220','ps_list: to be a comma seperated string, like "127.0.0.1:2220, 127.0.0.1:2221"')
flags.DEFINE_string('worker_ip', '127.0.0.1:2230','worker_list: to be a comma seperated string, like "127.0.0.1:2230, 127.0.0.1:2231"')
flags.DEFINE_string('task_mode', 'worker', 'runninig_mode: ps or worker.')
flags.DEFINE_integer('worker_num', 1, 'worker_num: used for allocating samples.')
flags.DEFINE_integer('task_id', 0, 'task_id: used for allocating samples.')

class Trainer(object):
    def build_graph(self, ps_str_list):
        var = tf.random_normal([3,2], mean=0.0, stddev=0.5)
        return var

def start_ps(ps_list, task_id):
    cluster_config = {
        'ps': ps_list,
    }
    print('cluster_config')
    print(cluster_config)

    sess_config = tf.ConfigProto()
    sess_config.allow_soft_placement = False
    sess_config.log_device_placement = True
    sess_config.Experimental.share_session_state_in_clusterspec_propagation = False
    sess_config.Experimental.share_cluster_devices_in_session = False
    sess_config.isolate_session_state = False

    server = tf.distribute.Server(
        tf.train.ClusterSpec(cluster_config),
        config = sess_config,
        protocol='grpc',
        job_name = 'ps',
        task_index = task_id,
    )
    server.join()

def start_worker(ps_list, worker_list, task_id):

    sess_config = tf.ConfigProto()
    sess_config.allow_soft_placement = False
    sess_config.log_device_placement = True
    sess_config.Experimental.share_session_state_in_clusterspec_propagation = True
    sess_config.Experimental.share_cluster_devices_in_session = True
    sess_config.isolate_session_state = False

    cluster_config = {
        'ps': ps_list,
        'localhost': worker_list,
    }

    server = tf.distribute.Server(
        tf.train.ClusterSpec(cluster_config),
        protocol="grpc",
        config = sess_config,
        job_name='localhost',
        task_index=task_id,
    )

    cluster_def = cluster_pb2.ClusterDef()

    worker_job = cluster_def.job.add()
    worker_job.name = 'worker'
    for i,v in enumerate(worker_list):
        worker_job.tasks[i] = v

    ps_job = cluster_def.job.add()
    ps_job.name = "ps"
    for i,v in enumerate(ps_list):
        ps_job.tasks[i] = v

    with tf.device('/job:ps/replica:0/task:0/CPU:0'):
        trainer = Trainer()
        var = trainer.build_graph(ps_str_list)

    with tf.Session(server.target, config=sess_config) as sess:
        res = sess.run(var)
        print('check{}: sess.run(var) = {}'.format(task_id, res))

    print('worker done')


def main(_):
    try:
        ps_list = FLAGS.ps_list.strip(' ').split(',')
        worker_list = FLAGS.worker_ip.strip(' ').split(',')
        worker_list = list(map(lambda x: x if ":" in x else "%s:%s" % (x, get_ramdon_port()), worker_list))
        task_mode = FLAGS.task_mode
        worker_num = FLAGS.worker_num
        task_id = FLAGS.task_id

        print('ps_list: ', ps_list)
        print('worker_list: ', worker_list)
        os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = ""

        if task_mode == 'ps':
            start_ps(ps_list, task_id)
        elif task_mode == 'worker' and task_id==0:
            start_worker(ps_list, worker_list, task_id)
        else:
            print('invalid task_mode. Options include "ps" and "worker".')
            sys.exit(1)
    except Exception as ex:
        print(traceback.format_exc())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    tf.app.run()
```

**start.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
source /env/py3/bin/activate
export GRPC_VERBOSITY="DEBUG"
#export GRPC_TRACE=all

python demo.py                \
    --ps_list "127.0.0.1:2270"                  \
    --task_mode ps                              \
    --task_id 0                                 \
    1>ps_log0 2>&1 &

sleep 1s

python -u demo.py             \
    --ps_list "127.0.0.1:2270"                  \
    --worker_ip "127.0.0.1:2220"                \
    --task_mode worker                          \
    --task_id 0                                 \
    1>log_0 2>&1 &

sleep 1s

python -u demo.py             \
    --ps_list "127.0.0.1:2270"                  \
    --worker_ip "127.0.0.1:2221"                \
    --task_mode worker                          \
    --task_id 0                                 \
    1>log_1 2>&1 &


echo "ok"
```

**Result**
Two worker processes successfully startup and finished. But the *var* has different value:

```
check0: sess.run(var) = [[-9.1801211e-02  1.3004950e+00]
 [ 1.2603621e-03  1.2598373e-01]
 [ 2.9150587e-02  3.2354552e-01]]

check1: sess.run(var) = [[-0.22149138 -0.06080906]        
 [-0.9715663  -0.25317684]                                
 [ 0.54541755 -0.04751018]]
```

Is it possible to make workers share dense and sparse values on cluster propagation mode?
I think it's an important feature for dynamically managing the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

The question is already solved.

[tensorflow issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/38519)